# HTML5 Canvas - fading/drawing in a dashed line animation

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I'm new to the HTML5 canvas, and I was wondering how I could replicate the following animation which is done in flash:

http://www.machinas.com/wip/esprit/games/2013_Spring_game

As you can see it draws in a curved dashed line, or it fades in an already drawn dashed line on the map. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: The whatwg specification includes a [setLineDash](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-setlinedash) method which is supposed to be able to do that, but unfortunately this isn't implemented by most (any?) browsers.